# WSO2 ESB aggregate with two respone

Tags: wso2, aggregate, esb, wso2-esb

I have create API with iterate and aggregate. But both response not combined. time to time both response showing as single. I have call this request as POST method and Info tag send as AD. inSequence section working. but outSequence tag both response not combined. Please help me to continue this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/Info" name="InfoRequestAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" protocol="http">
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="$body//Request/OptionInfoRequest/Info" name="OptionInfo" scope="default" type="STRING"/>  

            <script language="js"><![CDATA[var payloadXML = mc.getPayloadXML();
                var xml = '<ItemList>';
                for each (var item in String(mc.getProperty("OptionInfo")).split(',')) {
                    xml +='<item>'+item+'</item>';
                }
                xml +='</ItemList>';
                payloadXML.appendChild(new XML(xml));
                mc.setPayloadXML(payloadXML);
                mc.setProperty("ORIGINAL_PAYLOAD",payloadXML);]]></script>
            <iterate continueParent="true" expression="$body//Request/ItemList/item" id="option_info_request" sequential="true" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <switch source="//item" xmlns:m0="$body">
                            <case regex="A">                                    
                                <send>
                                    <endpoint>
                                        <http format="rest" method="post" uri-template="http://localhost:8280/oneOption"/>
                                    </endpoint>
                                </send>
                            </case>
                            <case regex="D">                                    
                                <send>
                                    <endpoint>
                                        <http format="rest" method="post" uri-template="http://localhost:8280/secondOption"/>
                                    </endpoint>
                                </send>
                            </case>                                
                            <default>
                                <send>
                                    <endpoint key="error_response"/>
                                </send>
                            </default>
                        </switch>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </iterate>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <property name="ECNCLOSING_ELEMENT" scope="default">
                <wrapper xmlns=""/>
            </property>               
            <aggregate id="option_info_request">
                <completeCondition timeout="10">
                    <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
                </completeCondition>                        
                    <onComplete xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="$body/*[1]" enclosingElementProperty="">                       
                    <send/>
                </onComplete>
            </aggregate>                
            <respond/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>                
    </resource>
</api>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In aggregate why is `enclosingElementProperty=""` empty, This property acts a a root tag for all the iterated result, you need to define the property and then use it in `enclosingElementProperty`, something like this

```
<property name="ECNCLOSING_ELEMENT" scope="default">
    <wrapper xmlns=""/>
</property>
```

and then

```
  <onComplete xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="$body/*[1]" enclosingElementProperty="ECNCLOSING_ELEMENT">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added like following code. This is working fine for me.

```
            <property name="enclosing_element" scope="default">
                <Reply/>
            </property>


            <aggregate id="option_info_request">
                <completeCondition timeout="60">
                    <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
                </completeCondition>
                <onComplete enclosingElementProperty="enclosing_element" expression="$env/*[local-name()='Body']/*">                        
                </onComplete>
            </aggregate>
```